# Delegate method for open the "Notification Center" in iOS 11

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, ios11

Which delegate method are going to be called when I open the Notification Center in iOS 11 (swipe down from the top of the display)?

In earlier versions up to iOS 10 the delegate method `func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` was called.

Thank you!

Illustration: [open Notification Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5kKn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change in iOS 11, its still the `applicationWillResignActive` that will be called.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) { ... }
```

Try it out yourself and you´ll see.

Comment: Though there is a little difference between iOS11 and earlier. The event (applicationWillResignActive) will just gonna called, when the Notification Center gonna dropped (more than 50% from view height). That's new, because in iOS10 the handler was called, when the swipe of NC did began. Thank you!

Comment: @F.Schmidt, when I test this in iOS 11 with a new app from an Xcode  9 template swiping down to display the notification center results in an immediate callback to `applicationDidBecomeActive()`, no delay.

Answer (score 1):

Rashwan L is correct. But there is more to this, at least in iOS 11 (I have not gone back to see if this behaviour is new in iOS 11).

When the swipe down is initiated there's an immediate call to `applicationWillResignActive()`.

If you do not commit the swipe (if you begin but don't go far enough or you swipe back up to release it) there's an immediate call to `applicationDidBecomeActive()`.

That's reasonable and expected behaviour. However, if you fully commit the swipe (you swipe far enough down so that the notification center remains when you release) the callbacks look like this...

```
applicationWillResignActive <- happens immediately

...the user is still dragging here...
...now the swipe is complete...

applicationDidBecomeActive
applicationWillResignActive
```

There is, unfortunately, an unexpected callback to `applicationDidBecomeActive()`. I think this is a bug but regardless, if you are taking action based on these events you need to be aware.